# angular 2 output and eventemitter doesn't emit

Tags: javascript, angular

i'm learning angular 2, and i follow this tutorial: https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-angular-2-building-a-toggle-button-component
but the whole part of the output and eventemitter doesn't work.
i do not get any errors and i can't figure out why it doesn't work.

this is my code for the togglelink component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-togglelink',
  templateUrl: 'togglelink.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['togglelink.component.css']
})
export class TogglelinkComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() state:boolean = true;
  @Output() onChange = new EventEmitter();

  onClick(){
    this.state = !this.state;
    this.onChange.emit(this.state);
  }

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and this is the code for the firstpage component that uses the togglelink component:
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {TogglelinkComponent} from '../togglelink/togglelink.component';

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-firstpage',
  templateUrl: 'firstpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['firstpage.component.css'],
  directives: [TogglelinkComponent]
})
export class FirstpageComponent implements OnInit {

  thetogglestate:boolean = false;

  firsttitle = "the first title";
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and this is the code for the template of the firstpage component:
    
      {{thetogglestate ? 'On' : 'Off'}}

```
</p>
<h2 *ngIf="thetogglestate">
  {{firsttitle}}
</h2>
<p>
  firstpage works!
</p>
```

when i change manually thetogglestate it does work, so i understand that the issue is with the output and the eventemitter part.

any idea why?

best regards

Comment: Not sure what you expect. You need `<app-togglelink (onChange)="doSomething()">` to listen to emitted events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `firstpage.component.html` template, you need to register some processing for this event to toggle the value of the `thetogglestate` variable.

Something like that:

```
<app-togglelink (onChange)="thetogglestate = !thetogglestate"></app-togglelink>
```

Comment: hey, thanks that works. but i thought the two way binding is doing it automatically, no?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, but there is a little work to do for this, i.e. a naming convention in fact. You need to use an output named `stateChange` (suffix `Change`). Now you will be able to use this: `<app-togglelink [(state)]="thetogglestate"></app-togglelink>`. In this case, you will have two-way binding for the `thetogglestate` property.